# How to configure headless Windows IoT application project to support async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, win-universal-app, windowsiot

[This sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/BlinkyHeadless/CS) shows how to implement a headless app, which worked for me on Raspberry Pi.

[This sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialSample/CS) shows an app that uses `Task` and async/await. It also runs on Raspberry Pi with zero problem.

However, when I add a function with `async` in it's signature and the return type of `Task` to the headless app project like that:

```
public async Task Test() 
{
}
```

I'm getting compilation error that informs me that it is not supported on Windows Runtime:

> error WME1038: Method
>   'BlinkyHeadlessCS.ReadMessagesFromDevice.ChangeDeviceMode()' has a
>   parameter of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' in its signature. 
>   Although this type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, it implements
>   interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types.  Consider changing
>   the method signature to use one of the following types instead: ''.

From this message I make a conclusion that the reason that it does not compile is that the project output type is WinRT. But I'd like to know **how to configure the project correctly so it acts similar to what the headed example does**?.

Specifically, I'd like the function in the example above to successfully compile and work as it does if added to the headed sample.

---

**What I tried so far**:

1. Changed the project output to the only other option available in the dropdown: "Class Library". Failed compilation with this error:

> error : One of your dependencies requires the .NET Framework, but the
>   .NET Framework could not be found in the NuGet packages installed in
>   this project.  Please install the appropriate .NET Framework packages
>   required by your dependency.

I'm not sure what "appropriate nuget packages" this error message could possibly refer to. I'm also not sure if "Class Library" is the correct output type.

2. Tried to remove the UI from the second example. Failed compilation with the following error:

> error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>   for an entry point

3. Tried to add add an empty Main in the app. Deployment failed with the following error:

> Error     DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2145615869

Comment: Is your async method public, and does it have to be? IIRC, there are limitations on what you can publicly *expose* in WinRT, but you should be able to *use* async/await internally. It's a bit confusing as you're not clear on how much the problem is to do with having a `Main` method vs picking the right project type, vs using async. I would try to nail it down to *one* issue to start with. Get something simple working without async, then introduce an async method.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for chiming in. I apologize that my question does not read clearly. The main points are: 1)headless app works but the output type WinRt so refuses to compile anything with Task 2)headed works perfectly with [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185501.aspx) 3) having troubles setting up the headless project that would use .NET for UWP apps `Task`

Comment: That still hasn't answered my question about whether the method is public or not - and there's a big difference between "not allowing an async method" and "refusing to compile anything with task" too.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are absolutely right as always. They are public, and it appears that this is the core reason of what I'm observing, sorry for not listening to you the first time around. Now I'm starting to see the light =) I'll do more research and I'll post back what I find.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I disregarded the possibility that this was a question about how to do a main loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet, making the methods private solved the problem, however I still do not understand why `public async Task Test() {}` compiles fine in a headed project but yields [WME1038](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977010.aspx) in a headless one.

Comment: @zespri: If that's the question you'd like to ask now, then it may well be worth asking that as a clear, separate question - it gets rid of all the other irrelevancies.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I edited the question, do you think it reads better now?

Comment: Somewhat. Although if this is an app (rather than a library), why do you need to expose a public method at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not. But it is interesting to know why it works in one case and the very same thing does not work in a very similar case. You did solve my practical problem, but I still would like to learn =)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following.

```
Install-Package Nito.AsyncEx
```

Then do the following in your code

```
public static class Program
{
    public int static Main()
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(MainImpl);
    }

    private async Task MainImpl()
    {
        //Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: @zespri In that case, I would suggest you contact Stephen Cleary directly about making his libraries UWP compatible. I think he would be more than happy to try.

Comment: How do I get `IBackgroundTaskInstance` then? I need to call [GetDeferral](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700507) on it so that runtime does not kill the app when the main method finished.

Comment: @zespri `Main` will not finish until `MainImpl` finishes. So simply `await` your `IBackgroundTaskInstance` in your `MainImpl`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the internal modifier in methods instead of public

Answer (score 0):

I don't use WinRT, but I'm pretty sure you aren't supposed to use Tasks in it.

From this blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/06/14/exposing-net-tasks-as-winrt-asynchronous-operations/

Looks like for async await in WinRT, you need to translate your return types:

```
void => AsyncActionCompletedHandler
Task => AsyncActionWithProgressCompletedHandler<TProgress>
Task<TResult> => AsyncOperationWithProgressCompletedHandler<TResult, TProgress>
```

The common interface implemented by Task and the WinRT equivalents is IASyncResult, as you might expect.

Comment: I don't *want* to use WinRt. The second example I'm linking is using Tasks and it does run on WindowsIoT/Raspberry Pi. I want to do the same. Going the WinRT route is certainly a direction I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I also acknowledge in the question that WinRT output type is wrong.

Comment: @zespri - whether you WANT to use WinRT is irrelevant to the confusion it caused you.  Fix up the method signatures and the confusion about the first error regarding Tasks is cleared up and the rest should all become clear to you.